# GEE, Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, libgee

I have been facing this error while opening geemap in google colab

AttributeError: module 'tornado.ioloop' has no attribute '_Selectable'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0Lea.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a technical answer, but I've encountered the same problem with geemap.

If you run the code block and let it fail, and then restart the runtime it should work the next time you run the same code block.

This has been happening with all of my older scripts for some reason. I would be interested if someone knows of a permanent solution.